# Is there a minimum page size on any x86 processor?

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-memory

I'm writing some code that needs the page size on the system it's being executed on. [sysconf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) will do the trick, but only if it's supported.

My question is this: if I find myself on a system where I can't dynamically  query the page size, is there a guaranteed lower bound on page size that holds across all x86 processors?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
$ getconf PAGE_SIZE
```

which should work with slightly higher reliability than sysconf as it is hardcoded into the kernel.

I believe the minimum size you will find in 99.9% of cases (?) is **4096**, which should also be the default size almost universally. It's been this way since 386 processors to my understanding.

Comment: For x86, the minimum page size is 4096 bytes, period. There has never been anything smaller and probably never will be. Too many data structures of the processor (e.g. Page Table Entries) assume the 12 bits at the bottom of a page's address will be clear.

Comment: It depends on MMU **and** OS implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum size is **4096**. It is impossible for a page table entry on x86 to point to anything smaller than 4096 bytes.